# Postgres trigger to only execute procedure when NEW.column = true

Tags: postgresql, triggers, ddl

Using PostgreSQL - I'm trying to fire a procedure that runs a trigger only when the `NEW` (inserted or updated) row has the `is_default` column value set to `boolean true`.

This is what I've tried but I get a syntax error on my `WHEN` line:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_price_group_default_price_handler
    BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT
    ON price_groups
    WHEN (NEW.is_default = true)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE clear_default_price_group();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you on a PostgreSQL version from before conditional triggers were introduced, but reading documentation for a newer version? `SELECT version()`.

Comment: yup (facepalm). Thanks Craig!

Comment: It's *always* a good idea to provide your version of Postgres. Helps to clarify a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason for apparently inexpliciable syntax errors in what looks like correct code is that the server version you're using doesn't understand the syntax.

For example, conditional triggers were [introduced in PostgreSQL 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtrigger.html), and are [not present in 8.4 or older](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html) so an 8.4 or older server will not have any idea what `WHEN ...` means there.

I've tried to make the argument on the pgsql-docs mailing list that we should include *"Since [version]"* alongside feature descriptions, but everyone just seems to prefer to direct people to read the docs for their version.  So I haven't got far. At least PostgreSQL has quick links to other versions' docs, unlike too many projects (*cough* *Hibernate* *cough*).

(This also means that you're on an old and unsupported PostgreSQL version and should upgrade).

Comment: That may be. Or it's the other elephant in the room. As for when features where introduced, the [Postgres feature matrix](http://www.postgresql.org/about/featurematrix/) may serve as a first guideline. And the convenient switching between version in the manual is also going a long way. `Since [version]` would make it even simpler, but the level of suffering is low due to these provisions.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be an oversight: `FOR EACH ROW` is missing:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_price_group_default_price_handler
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON price_groups
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.is_default)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE clear_default_price_group();
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

> If neither is specified, **`FOR EACH STATEMENT` is the default**.

Bold emphasis mine. You cannot reference `NEW` or `OLD` in a statement-level trigger, which makes the `WHEN` clause (referencing `NEW`) a syntax error - *in any version of Postgres*:

> Statement-level triggers can also have `WHEN` conditions, although the
> feature is not so useful for them since the condition cannot refer to
> any values in the table.

The `WHEN` clause was added to `CREATE TRIGGER` in Postgres 9.0.

It's unfortunate that the rare case `FOR EACH STATEMENT` is the default. Must be for historic reasons.

Aside: the expression `NEW.is_default = true` is just a noisy way of saying `NEW.is_default`. A `boolean` value can be used as expression directly.