# syntax Error in PostgreSQL when I try to create Trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I want to create trigger in PostgreSQL.

Logic is very simple.

I need trigger, if published_at updated and written_at is null, set published_at to written_at.

I wrote this one, but it failed. Does anybody have an idea?

```
CREATE function setWrittenAt() RETURNS trigger;
AS 
DECLARE old_id INTEGER;
BEGIN ;
old_id = OLD.id
  IF NEW.published_at IS NOT and NEW.written_at IS null
    THEN
    UPDATE review SET NEW.written_at = NEW.published_at where id = old_id;
 END IF ;
RETURN NEW;
END;
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER update_written_at 
    AFTER UPDATE OF published_at ON review
    WHEN (OLD.published_at IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.published_at)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE setWrittenAt();
```

Error:

**Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DECLARE"
LINE 3: DECLARE old_id INTEGER;**

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "DECLARE" LINE 3: DECLARE old_id INTEGER;

Comment: The body of the function (everything from `DECLARE` to `END`) must be a string literal, that is, enclosed with `'` or `$$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is based on `a_horse_with_no_name`s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61907625/5475071), since it'll throw an error.

`ERROR: statement trigger's WHEN condition cannot reference column values`

You need to add `FOR EACH ROW`, else conditional triggers will not function.

> If neither is specified, FOR EACH STATEMENT is the default.
>
> Statement-level triggers can also have WHEN conditions, although the feature is not so useful for them since the condition cannot refer to any values in the table.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29788879/5475071)

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_written_at
    BEFORE UPDATE OF published_at ON review
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.published_at IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.published_at)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE setWrittenAt();
```

I can not comment yet, which is why I've posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple errors in your code:

- `IS NOT` is not a valid expression you need `IS NOT NULL`.
- After `BEGIN` and the `returns` clause there must be no `;`
- you forgot to enclose the function body as a string (which is easier to write if you use [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)
- you also don't need an unnecessary (additional) `UPDATE` if you make it a `before` trigger

```
CREATE function setwrittenat() 
  RETURNS trigger
AS 
$$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.published_at IS NOT NULL and NEW.written_at IS null THEN
    NEW.written_at := = NEW.published_at; --<< simply assign the value
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then use a `BEFORE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_written_at 
    BEFORE UPDATE OF published_at ON review
    WHEN (OLD.published_at IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.published_at)
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE setWrittenAt();
```