# how to fix this trigger error in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I am getting a syntax error for my code which I can't understand why
am I missing something?
also, I read this I did not get my answer
[syntax Error in PostgreSQL when I try to create Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61907500/syntax-error-in-postgresql-when-i-try-to-create-trigger)

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyExampleName AFTER INSERT ON baskets
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE customers 
        SET customers.credit=customers.credit - NEW.amount 
        WHERE customers.id = NEW.customer_id;
END;
```

and tried it like this as well:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyExampleName AFTER INSERT ON baskets
FOR EACH ROW AS $$ BEGIN
    UPDATE customers 
        SET customers.credit=customers.credit - NEW.amount 
        WHERE customers.id = NEW.customer_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 2: FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
                     ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 67
```

Comment: Please read the linked question more carefully. A `CREATE TRIGGER` does not include the actual trigger code in the body. You need a separate `CREATE FUNCTION`  A complete example is also available [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE)

Comment: Which Postgres version are you working with?

Comment: @oxfist I am using last version

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the first comment on your question pretty much covers it all. You cannot put the trigger code in the trigger body, you *must* first create a separate function and include the function call inside the trigger body.

This example comes directly from the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE):

```
-- 1. Create the function that does what you need
CREATE FUNCTION emp_stamp() RETURNS trigger AS $emp_stamp$
    BEGIN
        -- Check that empname and salary are given
        IF NEW.empname IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'empname cannot be null';
        END IF;
        IF NEW.salary IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION '% cannot have null salary', NEW.empname;
        END IF;

        -- Who works for us when they must pay for it?
        IF NEW.salary < 0 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION '% cannot have a negative salary', NEW.empname;
        END IF;

        -- Remember who changed the payroll when
        NEW.last_date := current_timestamp;
        NEW.last_user := current_user;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- 2. Create the trigger with the 'EXECUTE FUNCTION function_name' part
--    replacing the actual function name from step 1.
CREATE TRIGGER emp_stamp BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION emp_stamp();
```